# Single Column Indexing on table that Contains NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, indexing, nvarchar

I am using a `Dimension` table to reduce the load on my final tables. The `dimension` table is used to store text. There is no limit to the no of characters involved and hence i have set it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. There is a identity column available on which I am creating an Single column index.

Would there be any problem while creating the index (because there is a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column in the table)?

The queries are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DIM_QUEST (Q_Key INT IDENTITY (0,1), Q_Text NVARCHAR(MAX));

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_q_text ON dbo.DIM_QUEST (Q_Key);
```

Comment: As long as you don't use `nvarchcar(max)` column in columns list of the index there will not be any problems.

Comment: Oh that's great!! But does it make sense to create Index on an Identity column?

Comment: Yes. `Identity` and `Index` are absolutely different things. I think, you need to read about indexing basics, for example here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/ or here: http://www.brentozar.com/sql/index-all-about-sql-server-indexes/